# Create a simple case-insensitive RegEx which is made up of ONLY vowels and prime numbers?

Tags: design-patterns, expression, matching

rules:

the entire string for the pattern must be 4 characters in size.

it can contain vowels (a, e, i, o, u) and the first 4 prime numbers (2, 3, 5 and 7).

make it so that if you enter a vowel in uppercase, it still works.

My solution/attempt:

`/^(?i)[a|e|i|o|u|2|3|5|7]{4}$/`

but I can't help but wonder if its the most compact way of doing it, there has to be a way to shorten this ?  ranges perhaps ? or break this down into two seperate expressions which work in unison ?

Using the above rules and expression the following would be observed:

E5i3 = TRUE ( valid )

o7A3 = TRUE ( valid )

0eiA = FALSE ( invalid )

is there a better way to shorten the expression i'm using ?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were a vastly superior way of doing this.

Comment: One small thing I just thought of, `[a|e|i|o|u|2|3|5|7]` -> `[aeiou2357]`.